# Game flicking chequers knocking opponents off

Tags: identify-this-game

My brother and I play this game using 8 white checkers and 8 black checkers on opposite sides of the board. We take turns flicking the checkers across the board to knock the opponent's checkers off the board. Once all the opponents checkers are gone, you win that round. We called this game "Chinese Checkers", but apparently [Chinese Checkers is a different game using a star shaped board rather than a square one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_checkers). So, what is this game supposed to be called?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this game has a name other than "The Game Some Guy And His Brother Made Up One Rainy Afternoon"?

Comment: I don't remember making it up, don't remember learning it from somewhere either, I just feel like I always knew this game

Comment: @PhilipKendall doesn't that describe all games? Something some guy made up one day?

Comment: yeah it was my question I posted

Comment: My username is "Some Guy" lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just googled "flicking Draughts game" and the first result was a wikipedia page on a game called [Chapayev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapayev_(game))

Details from the article include:-

> The game requires a checkerboard and checkers, eight pieces of each colour.

Which matches your question.

> During the first round, white pieces are placed on the first row, and
> black on the last.

Which fit requirement of "checkers on opposite sides of the board"

> A player takes their turn by flicking one of his pieces with the index
> finger to shoot it at one or more of the opponent's pieces.

Which again matches your description

> The game continues until only one colour remains on the board, winning the round.

Which matched the victory condition you describe.

Answer (score 1):

The game sounds like an attempt to play [Crokinole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crokinole) without a proper [Crokinole board](https://coolmompicks.com/blog/2019/09/27/how-to-play-crokinole/).

[image]

> With either two players or four players split into two teams, your goal is to shoot (or really, flick) discs into the center hole or higher scoring regions of the board, while also attempting to knock out the opposing team’s discs.

Without the center hole and pegs the game will naturally degenerate into simply attempting to flick the opponent's discs out of play.

Although not well known outside of Canada, Crokinole is a perennial favourite of kids and adults alike in Canadian summer cottages and games rooms.

Here is [a review video for Crokinole by ***Shut Up And Sit Down***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMKzeg78peg)

Comment: Good answer not sure how to handle this with the other question that was also asked

Comment: @JoeW: I didn't see another question. If there are two very similar questions, moderators can merge the questions together. I've raised a Moderator flag to suggest that.

Comment: I just noticed because I recognized the other question from the title before it got changed.